# Retrieve a set of DateTime values with intervals

Tags: c#

i need to fill a column in a datagridview with time values which has an interval of 30 mins. I have the start time and the timeinterval. I tried hard to use the below coding but it outputs only the start time on each and every cell of the column. could you please help me to retrive the required time values with 30min intervals. Thanks in advance

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
              //Reading the line which contains DISKXFER. Eg:"DISKXFER,T0001,0.5,0.0"
              if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
            {
               //split the line and insert to an array, Eg: split[0]=DISKXFER
                string dataLine = line.ToString();
                string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                int result = split.Length;

               //get the date at line 12. The date starts from 9th string and has a length of 11.
                string lineDate = GetLine(@"test.txt", 12);
                string getDate=lineDate.Substring(9,11);

                //get the start time at line 11. The timee starts from 9th string and has a length of 8.
                string lineTime = GetLine(@"test.txt", 11);
                string getTime=lineTime.Substring(9,8);

                //merge date and time
                DateTime TestTime = DateTime.Parse(getDate + " " + getTime);                     


                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                //split[] has four elements. Add those elements to four columns in the same row and continue with other lines
                for (int i = 0; i < result; i++)
                {
                    //add testtimes to the first column
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = TestTime;
                    TestTime = TestTime.AddMinutes(30);
                    //add split array to other columns in the same row of testtime. Eg: split[0] to column2, split[1] to column3, split[2] to column4, split[3] to column5
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = split[i];           

                }                  

            }

        }
        file.Close();
```

thanks for comments. I will attach the output that i receive and the output that i need
[image: A]

the output time values that i need is something like this given that the start time is 12:25 AM
[image]

Please refer the GetLine method given below:

```
public string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader ssr = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
                ssr.ReadLine();
            return ssr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file you are importing?

Comment: You are filling two columns. Are both columns showing incorrect values or just only one? Which column is showing incorrect values. Can you give as an example of what you expect and what you see?

Comment: You're assigning values to `dataGridView1.Rows[n]` inside your for loop, not `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`.  By brain compiler could be screwy, but won't that continually apply values to cells 0 and 1 of the same row?  Seems to me you'd be better off using `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(TestTime, split[i])` inside your for loop instead of the two current assignments.

Comment: @hansikaattanayake Is `GetLine()` a method in your code?  I'm not familiar with it.  If it's from your code, please edit your post and include the code of that method as well.

Comment: @hansikaattanayake one more thing: it would really help if you would post some example lines from text.txt or whatever your input file is.  You seem to be reading characters 9 to 19 of line 12 to get your date value, then characters 9 to 16 of line 11 to get your time value, and reading every line of the same file one at a time to get the values for the other columns?  Given your expected output it would help a lot to have an idea of your input.

Comment: @Adrian I have added comments with examples. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your comments and the example lines you provided, this should give you the output you were looking for:

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");

//get the date at line 12. The date starts from 9th string and has a length of 11.
string lineDate = GetLine(@"test.txt", 12);
string getDate=lineDate.Substring(9,11);

//get the start time at line 11. The timee starts from 9th string and has a length of 8.
string lineTime = GetLine(@"test.txt", 11);
string getTime=lineTime.Substring(9,8);

//merge date and time
DateTime TestTime = DateTime.Parse(getDate + " " + getTime); 

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
      //Reading the line which contains DISKXFER. Eg:"DISKXFER,T0001,0.5,0.0"
      if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
      {
          //split the line and insert to an array, Eg: split[0]=DISKXFER
            string dataLine = line.ToString();
            string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
            int result = split.Length;

            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            //split[] has four elements. Add those elements to four columns in the same row and continue with other lines

            //add testtimes to the first column
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = TestTime;
            for (int i = 0; i < result; i++)
            {
                //add split array to other columns in the same row of testtime. Eg: split[0] to column2, split[1] to column3, split[2] to column4, split[3] to column5
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[i + 1].Value = split[i];           

            }

            TestTime = TestTime.AddMinutes(30);
        }
    }
file.Close();
```

So all I did here was: moved the initial TestTime set outside of the while loop (because otherwise you'll always have the same time, not the successive 30 minute increments you said you were looking for), moved adding TestTime to the column outside of the for loop, because you only need to do it once per line, then changes your reference from `dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1]` to `dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[i + 1]` so that you add your other datapoints to successive columns of the one row.  Once the for loop is complete, then we add 30 minutes and move on to the next line.

Comment: It works. But it adds 150 minutes instead of 30. Anyway maybe it is not relevant to the provided questions. I will try to find the solution. Thanks alot for the correct answer.

Comment: Did you make sure to move the `TestTime = TestTime.AddMinutes(30);` outside of the for loop?

Comment: Yes I have moved it outsid

Comment: It works. there was another loop in the project. It has effected this. When i removed it, this worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = TestTime;
    TestTime = TestTime.AddMinutes(30);
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = split[i];           
}
```

For each "split" in an input line the body of the loop is executed. However, no new rows are added and the same two columns (0 and 1) are assigned in each iteration.

From the question it is not clear what you want to achieve but you probably need to fix this loop:

- If each "split" should create a new row in the data set then add this rows in the body of the loop.
- If each "split" should add data to a new pair of columns in the data set you need to use column indices `2*i` and `2*i + 1` instead of the fixed `0` and `1`.

Comment: Same thing said two different ways, just seconds apart :D